# How to operate with onfocus?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a textbox.

Now when the page is opened i want the textbox to have a default value.Once he click on the textbox the value should disappear and again when he removes his cursor from the text box ,the old value should come back.

So how do i do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a specific class to all textboxes on the page that you want to have this functionality.

Then, use this code to apply the functionality to the elements that have the class:

```
window.onload = function() {
   var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.yourClassName');
   for(var i = 0, j = elements.length; i < j; i++) {
      var element = elements[i]; 
      element.onfocus = function() {
         this.value = '';
         this.style.color = 'black';
      };
      element.onblur = function() {
          if(this.value == '') {
             this.value = this.getAttribute('defaultValue');
             this.style.color = 'grey';
          }
      };
      element.onblur();
   }
};
​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/6TmGA/1/

Comment: I just want a simple HTML guys !! No jQuery and other complex stuff :p

Comment: HTML cannot do that all by itself.

Comment: Simplicity is the key guys : onblur='if (this.value == "") {this.value = "To search, type and hit enter";}' onfocus='if (this.value == "To search, type and hit enter") {this.value = "";}'

Comment: But mine is way simpler mate.Not that i don't appreciate yours !

Comment: And it does the same thing in less steps !!

Comment: @5416339 "But mine is simpler..." Not when you're breaking best practices. Please, please, don't use inline Javascript events. Behavior shouldn't be floating around with the rest of your HTML content.

Answer (score 4):

Can you use jQuery?

If you can there are a lot of plugins that will help with this.

such as;

http://www.jason-palmer.com/2008/08/jquery-plugin-form-field-default-value/

Comment: You can add a focus event to the element using javascript and then check for a value etc.  lot more work than using jQuery and a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function setFocus() {

           document.getElementById('username').focus();

    }
</script>
```

Comment: 1. That's not the correct answer to this problem (read the question again, carefully. This doesn't answer it) 2. Use the correct formatting for your code (four spaces to create a code block) 3. When answering, try to give some explanation as to what your actually doing here, or link to the appropriate documentation